Executing a Python File from Robot Framework using Process Library
I am trying to execute a python file from Robot Framework using the Process Library as follows:
Example Test Case
    OperatingSystem.Should Exist    ${CURDIR}/../../../../../server.py
    Start Process    python.exe ${CURDIR}/../../../../../server.py    alias=PythonServer

The OperatingSystem.Should Exist is passing but the Start Process line is failing. I am getting the error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
I have also tried giving the absolute path following python.exe but that also is giving the same error.
I have also tried giving the absolute path of my python.exe
What is the right syntax to execute a python file from Robot Framework using the Process Library?

You missed the separation of the program and its arguments.
Here is an example:
*** Settings ***
Library           Process
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test Case
    OperatingSystem.Should Exist    ${CURDIR}/../wx_html_image.py
    Start Process    python    ${CURDIR}/../wx_html_image.py    alias=PythonServer


As you can see on the Start Process documentation, the *arguments are separated:


Thank you. For some reason, I thought "python server.py" was the command and didn't think "server.py" would be the argument to "python" command. This should have been the first thing I tried XD
